# stack navigation not working when using initialRouteName react native

Tags: react-native, axios, react-redux

React native app using native stack navigator, login.js import that handles login. When login is called as the initial route in the stack (initialRouteName="Login"), the stack does not navigate to the home stack when login is successful, but it does in fact work when navigating to the login from the drawer.

So in short, the login does work, but not when it is called as the initial route...

Here is the code from the app.js file:

```js
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
HomeStack = () => {
  // const [showSplash, setShowSplash] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    Translation.setLanguage('en');
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //   setShowSplash(false);
    // }, 2000);
  }, []);
return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Login"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <>
        <Stack.Screen name="preloader" component={Preloader} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="StackHome" component={HomeDrawer} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} />
          </>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <NavigationContainer>{HomeStack()}</NavigationContainer>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and here is the login.js code:

```js
const Login = ({navigation}) => {
  const settings = useSelector(state => state.setting.settings);
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [secureP, setSecureP] = useState(true);
  const [emailValid, setEmailValid] = useState(false);
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);
  const [type, setType] = useState('');
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigationforword = useNavigation();

  const validateEmail = userEmail => {
    let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w\w+)+$/;
    if (reg.test(userEmail) === false) {
      setEmailValid(false);
      return false;
    } else {
      setEmailValid(true);
      setEmail(userEmail);
    }
  };
  const login = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    if (email != '' && password != '') {
      axios
        .post(Constant.BaseUrl + 'user/do_login', {
          username: email,
          password: password,
        })
        .then(async response => {
          console.log("response",response)
          if (response.data.type == 'success') {
            setLoading(false);
            // if (response.data.userDetails.is_deactivated == "false") {
            dispatch(updateToken(response.data.authToken));
            dispatch(updateUserInfo(response.data.profile.umeta));
            dispatch(updateProfileInfo(response.data.profile.pmeta));
            dispatch(updateBilling(response.data.profile.billing));
            dispatch(updateShipping(response.data.profile.shipping));
            dispatch(
              updateProfileImage(response.data.profile.pmeta.profile_img),
            );
            dispatch(
              updateProfileBannerImage(response.data.profile.pmeta.banner_img),
            );
            dispatch(updateProfileName(response.data.profile.pmeta.full_name));
            dispatch(updateVerified(response.data.profile.pmeta._is_verified));
            navigation.navigate('StackHome');
            // navigation.reset({
            //   index: 2,
            //   routes: [{name: 'DashboardTab'}],
            // });
            // } else {
            //   setUserId(response.data.userDetails.userId);
            //   setUserToken(response.data.authToken.authToken);
            //   RBSheetRestoreAccount.current.open();
            // }
          } else if (response.data.type == 'error') {
            setLoading(false);
            setShowAlert(true);
            setType(response.data.type);
            setTitle(response.data.title);
            setDesc(response.data.message);
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          setLoading(false);
          console.log(error);
        });
    } else {
      setShowAlert(true);
      setType('error');
      setTitle(Translation.globalOops);
      setDesc(Translation.globalEnterData);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  const hideAlert = () => {
    setShowAlert(false);
  };
 // return the view etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was a conflict in the drawer which called the same component:

```js
<Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
```

Upon removing it, the login functioned as expected and navigated to the home screen.